# Fancybox3 position caption directly below image

Tags: fancybox-3

I'm using fancybox3 image gallery. When I add a caption using data-caption attribute the caption appears but is docked to the the bottom of the view.

However, I would like the caption to appear directly below the image instead.

I have looked through the documentation but can't find option to customize the position.

I have also tried overriding the default template base template moving fancybox-caption-wrap div into fancybox-navigation div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!